# mermaid.js (v10) "Diagram error not found"

Tags: javascript, mermaid

This works:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
    
    <pre class="mermaid">
    flowchart TB
        id0(["Created"]) --> id1("Public")
        id0 --> id2("Private")
    </pre>

<script type="module">
    console.clear(); //TODO: remove in prod

    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';

    mermaid.initialize({
        startOnLoad: true,
        logLevel: "warn"
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, creating the same `<pre>` dynamically (the eventual use case) and then running Mermaid does not:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
    
<script type="module">
    console.clear(); //TODO: remove in prod

    // Create the same `pre` as previous test:
    let pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.className = "mermaid";
    
    pre.innerText = `flowchart TB
    id0(["Create"]) --> id1("Public")
    id0 --> id2("Private")`;
    
    document.body.append(pre);

    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';

    mermaid.initialize({
        startOnLoad: true,
        logLevel: "warn"
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above shows a blank screen, and errors in the Console. (For reasons related to my employer's security policies, I can't actually inspect the page elements on my work machine. )

What is going on that Mermaid would treat these so differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you set the `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`. Setting `innerText` the way you are appears to be inserting `<br>` tags for the hard returns, which is messing up the Mermaid parser.

*(You might need to run snippet in full page mode to see that my example is working.)*

**UPDATE:**

It also works if you use `textContent` instead of `innerText`. I recommend you use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`, but they both work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
    
<script type="module">
    console.clear(); //TODO: remove in prod

    // Create the same `pre` as previous test:
    let pre = document.createElement('pre');
    pre.className = "mermaid";
    document.body.append(pre);
    
    pre.innerHTML = `flowchart TB
    id0(["Create"]) --> id1("Public")
    id0 --> id2("Private")`;
    
    import mermaid from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid@10/dist/mermaid.esm.min.mjs';

    mermaid.initialize({
        startOnLoad: true,
        logLevel: "warn"
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank. I could have sworn I'd tried `.innerHTML`, but perhaps I spelled it wrong. `.textContent` seems the better choice anyway. You're a hero.